# IIS URL Rewriting/Forwarding Tiny URL

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, alias, forwarding, tinyurl

I would like to rewrite/forward an URL on our internal network:

request: *http://shortcut/74b32*

rewriting: *http://myserver/Default.aspx?id=74b32*

I already have a DNS entry for **shortcut** that points to **myserver**.
**myserver** runs IIS6.

How can I implement the final mapping?

Thanks a lot
chris

Answer (score 0):

In iis 6 you will have to use a wildcard mapping to map to a handler that can manage the re-write/forward

Comment: Hi, thanks! 
I used isapi rewriting v3 to implement what I needed